# PowerShell regex to validate uppercase hostname

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to ensure a fully qualified hostname is uppercase. Example:

```
SERVER1.CONTOSO.LOCAL
```

I have tried:

```
"SERVER1.CONTOSO.LOCAL" -match "/^[A-Z]*$/"
```

But this does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong here:

1. `-match` (and `-imatch`) are case-insensitive. Use `-cmatch` instead.
2. `.` isn't part of `[A-Z]`, so your server name cannot match right now. The character class should probably be `[A-Z.]` in that case.
3. .NET regular expressions don't have any kind of delimiter (unlike e.g. PRCE). The `/` in there would right now prevent *any* match from occurring since right now the regex requires `/` to match before the start of the string, which cannot work for obvious reasons.

So the correct expression here would be something like this:

```
'SERVER1.CONTOSO.LOCAL` -cmatch '^[A-Z.]$'
```

You can also specify case-sensitivity within the regex itself, if you want; in this case `-match` would work as you require as well:

```
'SERVER1.CONTOSO.LOCAL` -match '(?-i)^[A-Z.]$'
```

And, of course, as [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48987607/73070) notes, you can often sidestep the problem with your solution by using an equivalent way. Here, by simply comparing whether the hostname matches the same one in uppercase.

There's often also a third way: Don't validate something that you can easily produce yourself. If you have input that needs to be uppercase, just turn it into uppercase instead of checking whether it already is. This eliminates the check and ensures that subsequent operations on the string get the input they expect.

Answer (score 3):

You can **simplify** your script by using the `ToUpper()` string extension. There is no need for using a regex here.:

```
$yourServerName = "SERVER1.CONTOSO.LOCAL"
$yourServerName = $yourServerName.ToUpper() # use this to ensure it is to upper
# or to test whether it is in upper case, you can do this:
$yourServerName -ceq $yourServerName.ToUpper()
```